# Execute different queries on each row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `tbl1` and `tbl2`. `tbl2` is where I store my data, and `tbl1` is where I have different queries stored to be executed on each row.

Example: Row1 might have query that extract max values from `tbl2`. 
Row2 on `tbl1` might have to query that extracts NOT NULL values from `tbl2` and so on...

I am using joins to run the queries and extract data from `tbl1` and `tbl2`

How can I iterate through each row on `tbl1` so that each query is executed one by one and results are stored somewhere?

I was thinking of using WHILE LOOP but my SQL knowledge if not that advanced and I am hitting a roadblock with this approach. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: This sounds odd, there is hopefully a better approach altogether.  Could you add sample data from each table?  How many unique queries are stored in tbl1?

Comment: Once you start storing queries in the system that you need to select and then execute you should step back and rethink your approach. This is almost always an indication that a poor design choice was made. If you can't fix the architecture then you are stuck using a loop of some kind and dynamic sql. This is just not the right way to handle data at all.

Comment: just add some examples for rows in your tbl1 and tbl2. Are you storing your whole query into a `NVARCHAR` field? or maybe you are using a more dynamic approach like storing _STATEMENT_ in some column, _PREDICATE_ in other column _VARIABLES_ in other column etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are storing these queries as text? If you need the queries to be that flexible than you will have to execute them using dynamic SQL within a cursor.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Sql 
FROM dbo.Tbl1;

OPEN curs;
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @sql;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    -- Assuming tbl1 contains expressions evaluating to a scalar value like 'MAX(Col1)'
    EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Results SELECT ' + @sql + ' FROM dbo.Tbl2');
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @sql;  --without this, your cursor will stuck
END;

CLOSE curs;  
DEALLOCATE curs;
```

There are security and performance disadvantages to using dynamic SQL, of course. I'm assuming these queries are being modified by an application or something. If they aren't going to be changing that often, you should consider making user defined functions / stored procedures instead of storing them in a table.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. When I implemented this, it does not move onto the next query, for some reason it keeps executing the first query in an infinite loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: that's because u must add a `FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @sql` right after your `EXEC` statement

Comment: you're welcome. However, for your personal knowledge, i would advice you about using cursors: there usually are many different solutions (better solutions) to do the same thing the cursor is designed for. Cursors and performance are known enemies, they can hide dangerous and not-easy-predictable effects, use them only if you have the full control of what you are doing.